# Nested XML layout file

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way in android to refer a xml layout file from another layout file. To explain better,

I have a layout file named layout1.xml & layout2.xml. 
Is it possible for me to refer layout2.xml from layout1.xml

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/layoutid" 
    layout="@layout/header" />
```

refer this doc:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

edit: fixed broken link

Answer (score 3):

Yes: you can use [include](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) or [merge](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html).

edit: broken links fixed