# Android UI design for tablet

Tags: android, user-interface, tablet, androiddesignsupport

I am implementing an app both for `phone` and `tablet`. I am not sure which `layout folder` and `value folder` are to be included in the project.Can anyone give me some idea about the `layout folders` to be included in the `res` folder of the app.

Comment: refer these links: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: This is opinion based question and too broad and as such it is off topic on this site. It is almost impossible to answer because it all depends on your project. You can have application where single layout and value folders will suffice, and you can have project where multiple ones are needed.

Comment: With a little research, you could have found what you're looking for. You want to include layout elements that scale properly for both phones and tablets.

[This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22220962/4924793) may help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can Use one Layout file to Use the all the Screens.

[image: One Layout Folder to use All Screens]

In above Picture the `layout` file is one for all screens by the Use the different `values`(dimens) folder.

values-w320dp ===> For Mobiles

values-w480dp ===> For 7 inch Tablets

values-w820dp ===> For 9 and 10 Tablets

The same `drawable` like in the Picture

`drawable-normal-hdpi` ==>For Mobiles

`drawable-large-hdpi` ==>For 7 inch Tablets

`drawable-xlarge` ==>For 9 and 10 Tablets

In Layout File :

```
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/login_edittext"
```

the `login_edittext` must be mention in all dimens folder at respective values

In `values-w320dp` inside the `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">15dp</dimen>
```

In `values-w480dp` inside the `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">30dp</dimen>
```

In `values-w820dp` inside the `dimens.xml`

```
<dimen name="login_edittext">40dp</dimen>
```

I think It will be help you..

Comment: Nice explanation. I will try out this.

Comment: @MamtaKaundal if you need landscape just create the layout file as layout-land inside this folder put the layout files for landscape

Answer (score 0):

According to http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html:

```
MyProject/
    res/
        layout/              # default (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-land/         # landscape
            main.xml
        layout-large/        # large (portrait)
            main.xml
        layout-large-land/   # large landscape
            main.xml
```

This will help with the available options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: And for tablet screens ?

Comment: Look at the link I have just added, there are multiple options to use. It depends how you are defining 'tablet screens'.

Answer (score 0):

For tablet, you must create folders with suffix

for 7':

> values-large
>
> layout-large

for 10':

> values-xlarge
>
> layout-xlarge

In theses folder, put a copy of some of your dimens.xml, integer.xml, layout.xml